# Can anyone convert this vb.net code to C#?

Tags: vb.net-to-c#, sharpffmpeg

I'm facing troubles with converting this code ( ***for using this [FFmpeg Wrapper](http://vbffmpegwrapper.codeplex.com/)*** ) to C# since it's the main language of my project .

I tried http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/
but the result code didn't work with me :(

I know it's a newbie request, I'm sorry ;

The Code :

```
    Public WithEvents MediaConverter As New FFLib.Encoder

    Private Sub ConOut(ByVal prog As String, ByVal tl As String) Handles MediaConverter.Progress
        OperationPrgrss.Value = prog
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub

    Private Sub stat(ByVal status) Handles MediaConverter.Status
        StatusLbl.Text = status
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to manually add event handlers using `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't have a strict equivalent for the `Handles` keyword; what you need to do is add event handlers yourself in the constructor.

```
public Form1() {
    ...

    // wire up events
    MediaConverter.Progress += ConOut;
    MediaConverter.Status += stat;
}
```

You don't need an equivalent for `WithEvents`, as that just tells VB there are events to be wired up, and in C# you do that yourself.

The rest is a very straightforward translation.  A `Sub` is basically a function with `void` return type, `ByVal` and the `Handles` clauses can go away, keywords are lowercase, and the rest is just semicolons and braces.

For example,

```
private void ConOut(String prog, String tl) {
    OperationPrgrss.Value = prog;
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```